# How to setup webpack config in typescript react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying to set up webpack config in react application. The purpose behind adding webpack configuration is to avoid caching of build files.

For development watcher mode and production minimized build.

Following is webpack.config.ts

const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.ts',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.4",
    "@types/react-alert": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.10.6",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/react-select": "^3.0.27",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.0.25",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "keycloak-js": "^11.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.2",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.13.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.12.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^3.1.1",
    "react-table": "^7.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^6.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "serve": "^12.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "styled-icons": "^10.22.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "wait-for-expect": "^3.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "develop": "webpack-dev-server --mode production"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.4.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest-teamcity-reporter": "^0.9.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.1",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-node": "^10.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.59.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,css,md,ts,tsx}": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

After running `npm run develop` I get following error

frontend@0.1.0 develop /c/Users/ui/project
webpack-dev-server --mode production

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/c/Users/ui/project/webpack.config.ts' config
[webpack-cli] webpack.config.ts:1:1 - error TS1208: 'webpack.config.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.

Answer (score 0):

create the react project with:

```
 yarn create react-app <project-name> --template typescript
```

to build:

```
yarn build
```

You don't need setting-up webpack.

Comment: This works. But my goal is to have to cache https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

Comment: This answer is misleading. There are cases when you need to configure webpack, instead of using CRA